# asp.net mvc jquery load not called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

what might be the reason for the jquery load not being called   , **i am not able to hit the uploadResults controller** ,i checked it with $(document).ready(function () { as well without it.  plz help?

```
function showStatus() {

        var progressbar = document.getElementById("progressBar");
        progressbar.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("uploadResult").style.visibility = "visible";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            **$("#message").load('Organization/UploadResults');**   
        });
        return true;
    }


            <form action="<%= Url.Action("FileUpload", "Organization")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="<%="uploadresult" + Lang.int_LangId %>" onsubmit="return showStatus()">
            <input type="button" id="attachButton" value="Attach File" onclick="showAttachFile();" />
              <input type="file" />

            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

            </form> 
            <div id="message"></div>                                      

            <iframe id="<%="uploadresult" + Lang.int_LangId %>" name="<%="uploadresult" + Lang.int_LangId %>" src="<%= Url.Action("MyImage","Organization", new RouteValueDictionary(new { OrgId = OrganizationMeta.int_OrganizationId, LangID=Lang.int_LangId })) %>"   width="150px" frameborder="0" height="150px" onload="showResult();">
            </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need more complete code really but the most obvious suggestion is to use firebug to see if any ajax requests are firing and what the response is.